# Android apps - Activity force back

Tags: android

My situation was like this, i have a home page of my apps name HomeGUI.java, there is a button in HomeGUI , when it have been pressed, it will bring intent and jump to the next activity ARTAAD_AR.java, my apps was an Augmented reality apps FYI, so when i was surfing around using my camera (in ARTAAD_AR.java), but strange things happen... whenever i surf for like 15 second, the activity will close and go back to HomeGUI.java which is my home page, this incident does not show any crash message like "unfortunately bla bla has stopped.", there is no any message, and it just auto force back to previous activity. Add-on, i have tried setting ARTAAD_AR.java as my first main activity, but it again force close and back to my smartphone home launcher without any notification.

This is my logcat : http://pastebin.com/dvi7MBML
This is my AndroidManifest : http://pastebin.com/Y5f46JJF

If you look at my logcat, please look at the Line 4 and 5, i suspect the started of Line 5 is the process of my activity have been force back or exit...

Just let me know if you need to see my HomeGUI.java and ARTAAD_AR.java

thank you.

Comment: you need to post the java files too

Comment: This is my java HomeGUI.java : http://pastebin.com/vXgQV51S
This is my java ARTAAD_AR.java : http://pastebin.com/TMm1fB7z

Comment: Looks like you are consuming too much memory.

Comment: anyway i can reduce it? i am not allow to reduce on adding marker ... pls help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In com/jwetherell/augmented_reality/ui/objects/PaintableObject.java

Try changing the method getTextWidth():

```
private StaticLayout measure(TextPaint textPaint, String text, Integer wrapWidth) {
    int boundedWidth = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    if (wrapWidth != null && wrapWidth > 0) {
        boundedWidth = wrapWidth;
    }
    StaticLayout layout = new StaticLayout(text, textPaint, boundedWidth, Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.0f, 0.0f, false);
    return layout;
}

private float getMaxLineWidth(StaticLayout layout) {
    float maxLine = 0.0f;
    int lineCount = layout.getLineCount();
    for (int i=0; i<lineCount; i++) {
        if (layout.getLineWidth(0) > maxLine) {
            maxLine = layout.getLineWidth(0);
        }
    }
    return maxLine;
}

public float getTextWidth(String text) {
    if (text == null) throw new NullPointerException();

    TextPaint textPaint = new TextPaint(paint);
    int widthWrap = 1000; // you may have to change this
    StaticLayout layout = measure(textPaint, text, widthWrap);
    return getMaxLineWidth(layout);
}
```

I believe this is a JNI issue and theses are work arounds for the known JNI issue. I haven't compiled the code, so there may some mistakes but you get the idea.

Comment: thank you so much for your efforts, i have tried the all three solution that you provided, the problem is still there, i have no clue on how to fix this problem....

Comment: this is the logcat that i run with your third solution -http://pastebin.com/j7Vsp2pg ,thank you

Comment: @Aaron Do they all fail with the same problem?

Comment: @Aaron I've added another idea above. Let me know if it works. There might not be a solution to this problem until an Android OS update fixes it.

Comment: Thank you justin, the problem still there , this is the logcat with your fourth solution, there a slightly different in the logcat if u notice, after the "DIRTY flag found,resetting all marker height to zero" and "Populating the cache", there are new Line stated "null clazz in OP_INSTANCE_OF, single-stepping" , other than this , i think all solution are with the same problem

Comment: Is there any chance wasn't the getTextWidth() method causing the problem>? because i only added 3 marker and the problem still there and activity close within 20 second... if i added 10 , the activity will close within 10 second

Comment: @aaron if I under stand the problem, it would only take 1 marker (for a longer period of time) to cause the issue. It's a memory leak at the API level, whenever the App calls getTextWidth() it loses a bit of memory. That method is called whenever a marker is displayed on the screen. The only workaround I can think of is to use an alternate method to getTextWidth() which doesn't have the memory leak. I have yet to find it.

Comment: i can see you work very hard on this , i really appreciate, but is is there anyway to make the activity to stay longer? i have to present to my lecturer on next month , if the apps keep close i afraid i might fail for this subject, sorry on keep giving you trouble , but you are the only 1 that can help me Mr justin

Comment: @aaron The easiest solution would be to borrow a friends Android phone for your presentation. As long as the phone isn't the same model as yours, you'll likely not see this issue. I've added a new edit, give it a try and let me know how it goes.

Comment: i tried EVO 3D and sony xperia ZL, and tablet Asus memo smart pad, the problem still there, i export to APK and install on these devices and yet the problem still there, but EVO 3D can last long for around 1 min before it close

Comment: OMG! MR Justin , it work like a charm right now!! i tried on my galaxy nexus , and it really worked , no more force close of the activity anymore, thank you so much!!!! and your source code as well!!! THANK YOU

Comment: it solved the problem now, but the text in the text box are out of allignment and be outside of the textbox, is there anything to do with the widthwrap?

Comment: @aaron No problem. Sorry your phone is so problemsome. I'll update the  issue tracker with this work around.

Comment: @arron yea, try increasing the widthWrap value.

Comment: Mr Justin, i tried increasing the widthWrap value, no matter how much i have increased, the text of the distance will be display outside of the box, and i try using ------>"textStr = name +"\n\n\n\n\n"+ "Distance: ("+ DECIMAL_FORMAT.format(distance) + "M)";" ..............But the distance text does not display on the next line, but on the same line, and outside of the text box

Answer (score 0):

[Removed previous answer, completely wrong].

I suspect you add too many markers, or you encounter [the following bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36908) in android.graphics.Paint.native_measureText (memory leak in a JNI wrapper)

Comment: i added 4 marker, but in future i got to add another 20s... so according to the link you posted, i shall remove the "//" to prevent crash?

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the same issue , but I resolved it by putting minimum sdk to 3 an targetsdk version to 4.

Thanks ..